# What's the process with requirements and design?

Tags: specifications

What is the usual way which requirements are managed and made sure to be fulfilled in designs? Sorry if the question is vauge and overly general but i'm just looking for a crude description.

Thanks

Comment: A design brief, or project brief is usually written based on a proposal from some source - customer request, marketing request etc

Comment: Google "product design specification" or "product requirements specification" (PDS or PRS)

Comment: @JonathanRSwift That's exactly what i was thinking about, but my question is more on how to turn those design specifications into design elements? Do you know anything about the transformation? Thank you very much

Comment: Validation and verification.

Comment: @DKNguyen I always read about V&V as being at implementation time, do you know how it applies to the design stages?

Comment: https://youtu.be/kl6ICgSscjY this livestream is happening right now and seems to be about your question

Comment: @RichardBamford You can check the design before it is built. Though for the project I was doing it on it was done after it was implemented but that project was a mess to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

There are Requirements-Managing Tools like IBM-Doors etc. (Many to find in Google).

A very general designing approach might look like:

- Set the requirements of the product and conserve it in a list (e.g.) or a Requirements-Managing-Software
- Create the product regarding these requirements
- Check if all of the requirements are fulfilled
- Redesign if necessary

Comment: I've used DOORS and CodeBeamer, among others.  They are tools but are useless unless the user understands Systems Engineering and requirements design.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend getting copies of some of the following to learn **how** to organize a project and its requirements.

IATF_16949_EN
INCOSE_SEHandbook
INCOSEGuideForWritingRqts
NASA_SystemsEngineering Handbook

These are pretty easy to track down online.